# How to fix "Uncaught error:Invariant Violation" error in ReactNative using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Element type is invalid:expected a string(for built in components) or a class/function(for composite components) but got: undefined.
This error is located at:
in V
in p
in V
in RCTView
In RCTView
in c

THIS MY Main.js File.

[image]

Comment: Show me the code that caused the problem.